# create instance of enclosing class

Tags: java

Let's say I have this structure:

```
  public class Foo {

        public class Bar {

        }

    }
```

Now how can I create an instance of Bar after creating a Foo?
Something like this but not this:

```
 Foo foo = new Foo();
 Foo.Bar bar = new foo.Bar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo.Bar bar = foo.new Bar();
```

Comment: cool thanks! Finally I see something other then a static approach :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo fooInstance = new Foo();
Foo.Bar barInstance = fooInstance.new Bar();
```

Comment: OP's inner class is not static.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your inner class `static`, so that you can reference to it without creating an instance of outer class.

```
public class Foo {

    public static class Bar {

    }

}
```

Now you can reference to `Bar` without creating an instance of `Foo`,

```
Foo.Bar bar = new Foo.Bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve

keep your inner class `non static`

```
class Foo   
{
  ...
  class Bar
  {
   ...
  }
}
 //then 
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo.Bar car = foo.new Bar();
```

Make you inner class `static`

```
public class Foo {
  public static class Bar {
  }
}
public class Test {
...
  Foo.Bar bar = new Foo.Bar();

}
```